# Access Email Address in Marketing Cloud Footer

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need the unsubscribe/manage subscription links at the bottom of our emails to direct over to our custom subscription management page. For users who aren't logged in, they need to be able to one-click unsubscribe.

To accomplish this, I'd like the unsubscribe link in the footer to contain a GET parameter with their email address. So it would be `www.ourdomain.com/unsubscribe?email=foo@bar.com`

In the footer of the account delivery profile, I imagine this looks like

`<a href='www.ourdomain.com/unsubscribe?email=%%=v(@userEmail)=%%'>Unsubscribe</a>`

Anyone know what the variable name might be for accessing a recipient's email address in the footer?

Bonus points: I'd love to know what variables I have access to in the footer. I can see that our existing code has access to
%%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%% and others, and that these are rendered out in the final email. Could you point me to the part of the documentation that tells me where I might find these things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found it! I was having trouble getting results in Google because these %%variables%% are called personalization strings. Searching for which personalization strings I have available to me returned the following link:

https://help.exacttarget.com/da-DK/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/

The variable i was looking for is %%emailaddr%%